# What is the effect of operating an electrolytic capacitor beyond the rated temperature?

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor

I know that the life expectancy of an electrolytic capacitor doubles by 10 degrees decrease in ambient temperature. Is this rule applicable when working beyond the rated temperature or maximum category temperature or not?

Answer (score 3):

It is not only about ambient temperature, but the actual operating temperature of the capacitor, which includes temperature rise due to internal heating from ripple current and ESR.

It is true that capacitors have a certain lifetime guarantee at certain temperature, but in general that rating is already given at the maximum operating temperature, and thus it would be invalid to estimate the lifetime at temperatures above it with the same formula, as the component would be used outside the rated operating tempetature range so none of the parameters would apply any more.

Panasonic has an application note about this, and it also says that if operating temperature exceeds the upper limit, it will result into rapid deterioration of electrical parameters  and irreversible damage to the capacitor.

So no, this rule cannot be applied, because it would require using the capacitor outside nominal operating conditions, and these have other ways to effect the lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know manufacturers of Aluminum electrolytic capacitors specify, after an endurance test:

1. The capacitance change
2. tan δ change
3. Leakage current change

after a certain number of hours at the maximum operating temperature and voltage specified.

---

Example

Test conditions:

```
T = 105 °C, VDC = 10 V, Time = 4000 hours, Initial capacitance = 470 micro Farads
```

Results:

```
Capacitance change <= ±25% of the initial value
D.F. (tanδ) ≦ 200% of the initial specified value
Leakage current ≦ The initial specified value
```

[image: Capacitor endurance]

---

See also the datasheet of United Chemicon KY Series capacitors:

United-Chemi-Con-1109128.pdf

---

I know the old rule that every 10 °C beyond the temperature of 20 °C capacitors' life halve but I actually trust what datasheets say.